# Jquery toggle input visibility on click and focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am working on a simple form that also uses place-holder text. I am implementing this behaviour with JQuery and not html attributes, mainly because the place-holder input also shows error messages to the user which need to be styled differently than plain place-holder text.

Right now the form behaves like this.

- Clicking on the input hides the the place-holder input and sets focus on the main input field.
- If the user has entered data then the place-holder does not show up.

Now this is all fine, but when the user presses the TAB key to change focus, none of the above happens.

Here is the relevant JQuery code and the HTML:

```js
$("#plh_username").click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
 $("#username").focus();
});

$('body').click(function(e){
 var target = $(e.target);

 if(!target.is('#plh_username')) {
  if ( $("#username").val() == "" ){
   $("#plh_username").show();
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="input" id="plh_username" class="inp_placeholder" value="Username" />
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
```

How can I achieve the same effect when the user selects an input field without actually clicking on one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [`.focusout()`](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) instead of `.click()`.

```js
$("#plh_username").focus(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $("#username").focus();
});

$('#username').focusout(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === ""){
        $("#plh_username").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="input" id="plh_username" class="inp_placeholder" value="Username" />
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
<input value="Press tab or shift+tab" />
```

Quote from the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/focus/):

> Elements with focus are usually highlighted in some way by the
>   browser, for example with a dotted line surrounding the element. The
>   focus is used to determine which element is the first to receive
>   keyboard-related events.

Comment: Shashank, thanks for the tip. I've switched to .focus(). What this now does is permanently hide the placeholder. As you press TAB all the placeholders disappear one by one. They should reappear on focusout() if the value of the actual user input is a blank string.

using focus() to hide() and using focusout() to show() the element is a problem. They cancel each other out and the placeholder just hangs there no matter what.

Comment: @user3494543 I edited my answer with a working snippet. Basically on `$('#username').focusout()` you check the value and see if its empty, if it is the placeholder gets shown again. I added a third input so you can easily press tab and shift+tab to focus off and on respectively. Clicking also works.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `.click()`. Use [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for onfocus event. This event triggers when a control gains the focus.

```
$("#plh_username").focus( function(){
  alert("focus")
});
```

for example see http://jsfiddle.net/wb2vef0g/